# Next-auth - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I use next-auth for login. Below is my code in pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].tsx

```
export default NextAuth({
providers: [
Credentials({
  name: 'Credentials',
  credentials: {
    email: { label: 'Username' },
    password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
  },
  async authorize(credentials) {
    const { email, password } = credentials as {
      email: string
      password: string
    }
    const authResponse = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    )

    if (!authResponse) {
      return null
    }
    const { user } = authResponse
    return { id: user.uid, name: user.displayName, email: user.email }
  },
}),
],
pages: {
signIn: '/login',
signOut: '/signout',
},
adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firestore),
session: {
strategy: 'jwt',
},
jwt: { encode, decode },
secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
callbacks: {
async jwt({ token, user }) {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/rest?apiPath=current-user/${token.sub}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': apiKey,
        Accept: 'application/json', // Add this line
      },
    }
  )
  if (response.status === 200) {
    throw new Error('user locked')
  }

  const data = (await response.json()) as CurrentUserApiData

  const { isSiteAdmin, isClinician, isPhysician, isKitter, isSystemAdmin } =
    getUserRoles(data.SystemUserRoles)

  token.user = {
    isSiteAdmin,
    isClinician,
    isPhysician,
    isKitter,
    isSystemAdmin,
    details: data,
  }

  return token
},

async session({ session, token }: { token: Token; session: Session }) {
  session.user = token.user
  session.user.email = token.email
  return session // The return type will match the one returned in `useSession()`
},
```

Here as you can see i manually trigger an error
if (response.status === 200) {
throw new Error('user locked')
}
the problem is this error i can't catch while log in. It shows
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
The next-auth gives that particular response as an html. I want to get the message "user locked". Please help

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this code is throwing error:

```
const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/rest?apiPath=current-user/${token.sub}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': apiKey,
        Accept: 'application/json', // Add this line
      },
    }
  )
  if (response.status === 200) {
    throw new Error('user locked')
  }

  const data = (await response.json()) as CurrentUserApiData
```

error code might be 404 or 500 that is why this if block

```
 if (response.status === 200) {
    throw new Error('user locked')
  }
```

is not running.

write the fetching logic in `try/catch` block and catch the error.

Comment: No the response is correct json. I manually trigger the error here 
  if (response.status === 200) {
    throw new Error('user locked')
  }
But this throw error next is sending as an html file

Comment: when you `console.log(response)`, is this correct response that you expect?

Comment: yes. I think next by default throws error as html. Is it so. ?